# Need help understanding how arrays work in javascript for objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having trouble understanding how arrays work in javascript.

Lets say I have an object, car

```
car = {
moving: false,
wheels: 4
};
```

Lets say I want to create an array now, of 5 of these cars. How would you do that? I would want to use a for loop to create them, but I have read many pages on js arrays such as http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp and I am still stumped.

I tried doing

```
carArray = [];
for(int i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
carArray.push(car);
}
```

However, when the program runs, there is only one car, not 5, and it is at the last entry of carArray.

Comment: When arrays and objects are assigned, it assigns a reference to the object, it doesn't make a copy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/grLoLdyb/1/

Comment: In this particular case, you have a typo: `int` should be `var` since JavaScript does not have type declaration.

Comment: You can create a prototype of car, so you can create 5 different car with new car(). 

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word `int` should be removed.  Then the code should work.

```js
carArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  car = {
    moving: false,
    wheels: 4
  };
  carArray.push(car);
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. I thought you were only supposed to use the declaration once, not in a for loop like that. Thank you!

Comment: You can do it either way, actually.  Please accept my answer if it works for you. @qwerty54